# unable to make connection with mongodb from nestjs after new installation version are nestjs v 9.1.1 and moongose 7.1.1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, versionupgrade

First I have updated the versions in my running app.

From nestjs version v-6 upgraded to nestjs v9.0.0 and "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.2.2",

and mon*your text*goose version from v5.6 to 7.1.1
"mongoose": "^7.1.1",
"mongoose-unique-validator": "^4.0.0"

now i can make a db connection with same old working code.

then i created a fresh installation with a new project with updated versions.

but getting same errors.

```
MongooseModule.forRoot(

      // `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_HOST}`,
      // {
      //   user: process.env.MONGO_USER,
      //   pass: process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD,
      //   dbName: process.env.MONGO_DATABASE,
      //   w: 'majority',
      //   retryWrites: true
      // },

      `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGO_HOST}/${process.env.MONGO_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    ),
```

> ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying

MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined

i have tried a making a new connection with mongoose and it worked

const conn =  await mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGO_HOST}/${process.env.MONGO_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,options);

```
  console.log('conn === ',conn);
```

but from MongooseModule its not creating a connection.

i just wanna a solution to make a db connection with updated version of mongoose and nestjs.

Thanks